# bool masking in numpy array matrices

Tags: python, numpy

I have following program

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.randn(3,4)
print(arr)

regArr = (arr > 0.8)
print (regArr)
print (arr[ regArr].reshape(arr.shape))
```

output:

```
[[ 0.37182134  1.4807685   0.11094223  0.34548185]
 [ 0.14857641 -0.9159358  -0.37933393 -0.73946522]
 [ 1.01842304 -0.06714827 -1.22557205  0.45600827]]
```

I am looking for output in arr where values greater than 0.8 should exist and other values to be zero.

I tried bool masking as shown above. But I am able to slove this. Kindly help

Comment: Look into `np.where` with three inputs.

Comment: Shouldn't there be only two zeros in final output, given only two `False`s in the `regArr`?

Comment: The example doesn't match the description. `-0.06714827` and `True` should give `-0.06714827`, not `0`.

Comment: corrected problem description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what exactly you want to achieve, but this is what I did to filter.

```
arr = np.random.randn(3,4)
array([[-0.04790508, -0.71700005,  0.23204224, -0.36354634],
       [ 0.48578236,  0.57983561,  0.79647091, -1.04972601],
       [ 1.15067885,  0.98622772, -0.7004639 , -1.28243462]])

arr[arr < 0.8] = 0
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [1.15067885, 0.98622772, 0.        , 0.        ]])
```

Thanks to user3053452, I have added one more solution which the original data will not be changed.

```
arr = np.random.randn(3,4)
array([[ 0.4297907 ,  0.38100702,  0.30358291, -0.71137138],
       [ 1.15180635, -1.21251676,  0.04333404,  1.81045931],
       [ 0.17521058, -1.55604971,  1.1607159 ,  0.23133528]])

new_arr = np.where(arr < 0.8, 0, arr)
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [1.15180635, 0.        , 0.        , 1.81045931],
       [0.        , 0.        , 1.1607159 , 0.        ]])
```

Comment: note that this solution makes changes to `arr` forever, while `np.where()` does not.

Comment: @user3053452 thank you for your suggestion, I have added one more solution accordingly.

Comment: while it's all nice that you added 2nd solution, please set `random seed` to compare values or just use same arrays to get same results.